# laurent series expansion about $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

[image]

using the Laurent expansion i got the answer to be $$-(z+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n-1}}{2^{n+1}}$$ however, I've got a feeling I've made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

By partial fractions, $g(z) = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{z} - \frac{3}{4} \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}} =   -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{z} - \frac{3}{4} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^i}{2^i}$.

Comment: Similar to Batman's answer, consider first the Taylor series of $zg(z)$ around $z=0$

Comment: There was a typo on the sign of the $z^{-1}$ term.  I took the liberty of fixing it.  I hope that you don't mind.